# How to create non-repeating "Time of Day" automations?

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I just discovered the "Time of Day" personal automations, and they are great. The only problem is that sometimes I'd like the automation to not be triggered recurrently. For example, when scheduling the sending of a WhatsApp text.

In the "REPEAT" section I am asked to choose between "Daily", "Weekly" and "Monthly":

[image: Personal Automation "REPEAT" section]

Is there a way to create non-repeating "Time of Day" automations?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is a way with the shortcuts app, you have to use a third party app if you want that feature which makes absolutely no sense to me. It’s not like it’s something that would be hard to program, especially if you have the repeat time frames available. This was asked over a year ago and they still haven’t made any updates to the app :/